# Intellij: Spring facets don't get detected correctly: AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer never runs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have this class:

```
public class MyAppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("started!");
        ...
```

When I run Tomcat in Intellij it says `Deployed successfully` but the `started!` never gets printed in console; then when I got to `localhost` in browser I get `404` error.

This is how the facets window looks like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M60Zj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5lvU.png)

I'm not sure what to do.

I tried to change it like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woT2k.png)

but same result

```
package test.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;
import test.security.SecurityConfig;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

public class MyAppInitializer extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext sc) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("startup!");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        root.register(WebConfig.class);
        root.setServletContext(sc);

        root.scan("test");
        //sc.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet =
                sc.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(new GenericWebApplicationContext()));
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        appServlet.addMapping("/");
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SecurityConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

```
package test.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("test")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "test",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }


    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

```
package test.security;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```
package test.security;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;
import test.config.WebConfig;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
        AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class, WebConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: `then when I got to localhost in browser I get 404 error.` - are you sure you are entring the correct url address? Provide the [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) project.